# Ajuda com criação de objeto

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Como coloco o método `descontoINSS` nessa página?

```
<?php
include_once("Pessoa-class.php");
include_once("PessoaFisica-class.php");
include_once("Funcionario-class.php");
include_once("index.php");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$CPF = $_POST['cpf'];
$salario = $_POST['salario'];

$Funcionario = new Funcionario();
$Funcionario->setNome($nome);
$Funcionario->setSexo($sexo);
$Funcionario->setSalario($salario);
$Funcionario->descontoINSS($x);
echo "O valor de desconto do INSS é R$ $x";
?>
```

sendo que o método está nessa classe?

```
<?php
    class Funcionario extends Pessoa {
        private $salario;
        public function getSalario(){
            return $this->salario;
        }
        public function setSalario($salario){
            if ($salario<0)
                echo "ERRO: Salário não pode ser negativo";
            else
                $this->salario = $salario;
        }
        public function descontoINSS($x){
            return $x = 0.11*$this->salario;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Declare uma variável que receberá o retorno do método `descontoINSS` ... `$x = $Funcionario->descontoINSS($salario);`

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pois aparentemente o usuário foi removido.

Comment: Ué, o autor da pergunta mal chegou e já foi embora?

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom tinha o nome de Carla, fez a pergunta, editou na mesma hora em que eu estava ajustando a formatação, e depois simplesmente sumiu.